# Why do I need a scope.$apply when setting $location.path

Tags: angularjs, scope

Given this simple example where I have a directive that intercepts the click on a element and then uses the $location service to navigate somewhere. Why do I need to wrap the $location.path() call in a $scope.$apply?

HTML:

```
<a my-href="/">Click me</a>
```

Script:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myHref', function(){
        return {
            controller: function($scope, $location){
                $scope.navigate = function(path){
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                        $location.path(path);
                    });
                };

            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
                elem.bind('click', function(){
                   scope.navigate(attrs.myHref);
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/basslagter/4mya2uv0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not generally need it because updating location using angular `$location` service needs a digest cycle to happen to update the location. In your case you need it because you are calling the scope function from manually bound click event (as opposed to using an ng-click) which is outside angular context (angular has no idea if something event has happened and it has updated the scope). Also you have it in the wrong place, because when you use `scope.apply` it must be placed on the top of the call stack, i.e the place of origin, otherwise your scope function becomes unusable when invoked within the angular context. Also it is a weird thing sometimes when you perform digest cycle manually within a controller.

For example:

```
 angular.module('app').directive('myHref', function(){
    return {
        controller: function($scope, $location){
            $scope.navigate = function(path){
               $location.path(path);
            };

        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            elem.bind('click', function(){
               scope.navigate(attrs.myHref);
               scope.$apply(); //<-- Here
            });
        }
    }
});
```